# Error when trying to perform use Django CommentForm in view

Tags: ajax, django, comments

I am trying to use the built-in Django CommentForm in my view, but I keep getting the error:
`'QueryDict' object has no attribute '_meta'`

My View:

```
def comments(request):
    if request.is_ajax() and request.method == "POST":
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_comment = form.save()
            return HttpResponse(new_comment)
```

I'm aware of the built-in comment template tags, but don't think they will work as easily for my application.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

When initializing the `CommentForm`, the first argument should be the object that the comment relates to.

```
form = CommentForm(obj, data=request.POST)
```